# ERROR Error: Exception in HostFunction: expected 0 arguments, got 1, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I tried to implement a way to track the position of the users phone. Therefore, I installed expo-location. After installing it with npm i expo-location, I got the following error:

Error: Exception in HostFunction: expected 0 arguments, got 1, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Since it was just a test to see how 'good' expo-location is working I decided to uninstall it again with npm uninstall expo-location. Unfortunately, it did not remove the error.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "start-dev": "APP_VARIANT=development expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.20",
    "@react-navigation/core": "github:react-navigation/core",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.18",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.14",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "ansi-escapes": "^6.2.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "color": "^4.2.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "^2.4.12",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.18",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "isaac": "^0.0.5",
    "mobx": "^6.7.0",
    "mobx-persist": "^0.4.1",
    "rc": "^1.2.8",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-alert-notification": "^0.3.5",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-crypto-js": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.4",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-loading-modal": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-tabs": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.2",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "ws": "^8.15.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "reactotron-react-js": "^3.3.8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have already tried to remove package-lock.json and reinstall the whole sh*t, but nothing gets my project to work. I'm looking forward to helpful advice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77971299/react-native-a-module-failed-to-load-due-to-an-error-and-appregistry-registerc

Comment: @GeorgeMuders thanks for your comment, but you are directing to a question which wasn't answered correctly. Nevertheless, I updated react-native-reanimated and react-native-gesture-handler and as expected it did not fix my problem.